# node-canvas issue with loading custom fonts using registerFont()

Tags: node.js, express, canvas

**Note**: I have tried multiple fonts so problem is not in font files... Keep getting this error below and output in fallback font...

(process:22832): Pango-WARNING **: 12:52:05.268: couldn't load font "Zen Dots Not-Rotated 40px", falling back to "Sans Not-Rotated 40px", expect ugly output.

**Steps to reproduce:**
registerFont("./ZenDots-Regular.ttf", {
family: "Zen Dots",
});

```
const canvasInit = canvas.createCanvas(1000, 500);
const ctx = canvasInit.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = '40px "Zen Dots"';

const color = "#ffffff";
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fillText(
  "Whereas disregard and contempt for human rights have resulted",
  10,
  100
);
// etc.
```

**Expected result:**
Generated image with text that is using custom font declared above.

**Actual result:**
Generated image with text that is using fallback default font. Which is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this issue and was able to resolve it by downgrading to version 2.10.2 of the canvas package:

```
npm install canvas@2.10.2
```

Reference: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/2191

Hope this helps!